# Is there a way to disable automatic type conversion in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I tried to insert a json
`{"Name" : "abc", "Age" : 28}`.

When I retrieve back the doc using Java, I got
`FindIterable<Doc> {"Name:" "abc", "Age" : 28.0}`.

Is there a way to disable this type of conversion from int to float in mongodb, other than inputting as `NumberInt()`?

Comment: It depends on how you are doing it in the first place. In most instances if you actually specified `Integer` as the actual type when inserting the data in Java code then it would indeed be stored as an integer in BSON and retrieve as one. It's also possible to have a strongly typed query or other operation to a class definition matching the result document, where that property is also an integer. But if you are just expecting something actually stored as a `Double` to come back as an `Integer` with a plain BSON document, then that "should not" happen is it just would not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer...I guess it makes sense as you pointed out..But here I am trying to index a user input file as there is no straight way to determine the type of the value...But it seems I need to figure out before indexing the collection..